# get value from async function in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using [async storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/) to retrieve my data but how do I use it with useState()?

Example:

```
async function getdata(){
let d= await AsyncStorage.getItem('Name');
return d;
}

export default function App() {
 const [name, setName] = useState(() => getdata());
 return (<View>...</View>)
}
```

but this doesn't work since getdata() is async, so how do I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention I tried the useEffect() Hook like this:

```
async function getdata(){
let d= await AsyncStorage.getItem('Name');
console.log('retrieved Data!');
return d;
}

const [name, setName] = useState(()=>0);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(setName);
    console.log('moving on...');
  }, []);
```

but the order of execution was:

> 'Moving on...'
> 'retrieved Data!'

where as it should have been the other way around

Comment: In response to the edit, the reason why 'moving on' resolves first is because getData is an asynchronous function. That means that the program won't wait for getData to finish executing before moving to the next line. This is fine. It just means that the component will 'render' once without the name set, then will re-render  again when setName is called, at which point the 'name' variable will be populated with whatever came out of asyncstorage.

It's not necessary to place a callback function in useState() in this case. Initializing it to some literal is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll initialize your state to some empty value. Maybe an empty string, maybe a null. If you like, you can have your component render something different during this time, such as a loading indicator. Then once the data loads, you can set state to render again.

```
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(value => setName(value));
  }, []);

  if (name === null) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>
  } else {
    return (<View>...</View>)
  }
}
```

Comment: `getData().then(setName);` :)

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to mention I tried this but I'm still not getting the desired effect, you can see in the edit of the question

Comment: @cakelover your edit shows `getData().then(setName(value));`, which is wrong. It sets the state *immediately*, and passes the result into `.then`. Change it to `getData().then(value => setName(value));` or `getData().then(setName);`

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry I had written `getData().then(setName);` in my actual code, I accidently wrote it the wrong way in the edit, I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `useEffect`

```
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrap = async () => {
      const name = await getdata();
      setName(name);
    };
    bootstrap();
  }, []);
  return <View>...</View>;
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't give the desired results, My apologies I forgot to mention it in the question, I've made the edit now

Comment: @cakelover what's the problem?

Comment: The order of execution, you can see in the edit below where I mentioned it should be the other way around i.e. getdata then move on

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here is to initialize name as false, and then use 'setName' in a .then() callback. setName (and those setter functions that come out of useState generally) is meant to be a way of updating that value asynchronously.

I'm setting name to the boolean 'false' here and checking it strictly. If there is a case where that name field is empty it can just be set to an empty string without causing an infinite loop.

```
async function getdata(){
let d= await AsyncStorage.getItem('Name');
return d;
}

export default function App() {
 const [name, setName] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (name === false) {
   getData().then((name) => {
    setName(name);
   });
  }
 }, []);
 
 return (<View>...</View>)
}
```

Keep in mind that your view has to be able to deal with a false name value. How it does that is up to you.

^^^The above solution should effectively solve your problem but I'll make a quick note here: If your component is relatively complex it might be re-rendering a number of times for other reasons and will consequently run the if(name === false) condition as it waits for the callback to resolve. This won't break things but it'll hammer async storage more than necessary and might affect performance. If you find that to be the case, look into 'debouncing' callbacks using the helpful article below.
https://medium.com/@gabrielmickey28/using-debounce-with-react-components-f988c28f52c1

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little slow, I still don't understand what the usage of `if (name === false)` is? like won't it always be true since we've initialized it as false before hand? are u suggesting it as a buffer like adding 'Loading' text while the values are fetched?

Comment: It allows you to avoid reloading the name from async storage at each re-render since 'false' is effectively a flag saying 'this hasn't been loaded yet.' 

After the name is fetched initially from storage, it's pulled into your component and does not need to be fetched again.

Comment: I'm not sure but couldn't `useState(()=>false)` also avoid rendering each time?

Comment: useState only initializes the value on first render. Subsequent render cycles, like one triggered by setName when getData's callback resolves, won't re-initialize the 'name' to false.