# How to setState with value returned by an async function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I am attempting to setState (adding an element to an array) following an async function call. However `images` is set with `undefined`. (Even though underlying function definitely returns with a value.)

How do I make sure my array is updated with value after return from async function concludes?

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])
```

```
pickerResult.map(async (img) => {
    await handleImageUpload(img.uri)
    .then((url) => {
    setImages(images => [...images, url]);
    })               
})
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(images)
    }, [images])
```

```
Array [
  undefined,
  undefined,
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get value from async function in useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428208/get-value-from-async-function-in-usestate)

Comment: The answer below helped me resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])
pickerResult.map(async (img) => {
    const url = await handleImageUpload(img.uri)
    setImages(images => [...images, url]);              
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately same outcome with elements in images being set as undefined

Comment: Can you add the response you're receiving from `handleImageUpload(img.uri)` API in the question?

Comment: Your comment lead me to be able to solve this. `handleImageUpload()` calls another async function; which it wasn't waiting for before returning. Hence the `undefined` values. I was logging the wrong const for a while, hence not realizing. I have adjusted my code to your solution and it works! TY